# How to insert a node arbitrary in a liked list?

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I'm about to implement a function that is able to insert a node in a linked list arbitrary . The Code below works properly for inserting a node at the first of the list but for putting a node after another node it doesn't work . I honestly can't figure out that what's the matter with this code. Also when I'm tracing the code I can't find out my mistake.please don't ban me and help me solve this matter . Thanks in advance.
Class Node Comes :

```
public class Node {
Object Element;
Node Link;

public Node() {
    this(null,null);
}

public Node(Object Element, Node Link) {
    this.Element = Element;
    this.Link = Link;
}

}
```

Class List :

```
 public class List {
Node FirstNode;
Scanner UserInfo = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner UserInput = new Scanner(System.in);
public List() {
    FirstNode = null;
}
public void InsertArbitrary() {
int Location = UserInput.nextInt(); // Location of new node
if (Location == 1) {
    Object Element = UserInfo.nextLine();
    FirstNode = new Node(Element, FirstNode); // locates a New Node At First
} else {
    Object Element = UserInfo.nextLine(); // Content of new node
    Node CurrentNode ; // for searching in the list 
    CurrentNode = FirstNode;
    for (int i = 1; i <= Location - 1; i++)
        CurrentNode = CurrentNode.Link;
    Node NewNode = new Node (Element , CurrentNode);
}
}
}
```

Comment: There is not enough context code to understand what it does.

Comment: (If you want faster answers, don't violate the naming convention rules.)

Comment: @Froggy.I added more details

Comment: @ErFun Java variable and method names start with a lower case letter. Your naming convention makes everything LookLikeAClass.

Comment: Your code won't work to insert in first position either... You're just creating the node, not linking it with the next (and previous) one.

Comment: @m0skit0 First position doesn't have a previous position. it works fine and properly for adding a node in first position . my problem is to insert a node after another node.

Comment: But it has a next element if the list is already created. In your code, when you insert an element as first, the rest of the list is gone.

Comment: @m0skit0 The 2nd argument to the Node contructor is the reference to the next node. So the rest of the list is preserved because the next pointer of the new node references the old head of list and becomes the new head of list.

Comment: @m0skit0 for example you add 1 as the 1st position . then you add 2 as the first position , as an output I have a node contains "2" and points to a node contains "1" and this node is also pointing to null . it's working fine here .

Comment: @chiaboy Yeah, right, didn't see that. Strange ways to code...

Answer (score 1):

Once you've iterated to the location for insertion, you properly create a new node and assign it's link to the next element. But what you're not doing is updating the previous link to POINT TO your new node, so the tail of your list is not longer reachable from the head node.

You must do something like this (untested):

```
Node FirstNode;
int Length = 0;
public List() {
    FirstNode = null;
}
public void InsertArbitrary(int Location, Object Element) {
    if (Location == 1 || Length == 0) {
        FirstNode = new Node(Element, FirstNode); // locates a New Node At First
        Length++;
    } else {
        Node CurrentNode ; // for searching in the list
        CurrentNode = FirstNode;
        for (int i = 1; i <= Location - 2 && i < Length; i++)
            CurrentNode = CurrentNode.Link;
        Node NewNode = new Node (Element , CurrentNode.Link);
        CurrentNode.Link = NewNode;
        Length++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not working . I'm getting this error " Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException " and this error belongs to "    Node NewNode= new Node (Element , CurrentNode.Link); "

Comment: When inserting into arbitrary locations in a linked list, you must mind the current length of the list to avoid stepping out of bounds. For example, inserting into location 5 of an empty list is meaningless. I've updated my code snippet to express this. Of course you should also test out your code to determine that the location indices are being correctly managed.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're not updating the reference to the next node.

Without giving you the code (because this is homework), given you want to insert a new node X after A, in pseudo code:

```
x.next = a.next
a.next = x
```

So the chain fragment changes from `a -> b` to `a -> x -> b`